# Trouble understanding the supersymmetric localization argument

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, supersymmetry

A standard technique in supersymmetric quantum field theory is localization. Due to supersymmetry, one can show that only a small subset of the space of all field configurations contributes to the path integrals which define correlation functions, thus simplifying their calculation enormously. There are two standard arguments that supersymmetric path integrals localize.

The first localization argument is basically a sort of fixed point theorem, see for example Section $5$ of [This paper by Witten](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9112056v1). This argument makes it quite clear that the subset of fields on which these integrals localize is the set of fixed points of the supercharge $Q$, i.e. those for which the SUSY variation of all fields vanish. From here, it is clear to me that the integrals should localize to configurations for which the fermions and their $Q$-variations all vanish.

The second argument is more direct, and lends itself better to calculation. For a theory with a $Q$-invariant action $S$, one can show that the following path integral is independent of the parameter $t$
$$
Z_{t}
=
\int[\mathcal{D}X]e^{-S[X]-tQV[X]}
$$
for any "not too extreme", functional $V$.

It is then clear that (given good enough convergence properties), we can compute the original integral by taking $t\to\infty$. In this limit, the only field configurations which provide a non-zero contribution to the integral will be those for which $Q\cdot V=0$. To proceed with actual calculations, one must make a choice of $V$, the canonical choice (see for example [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.09205), [here](https://doi.org/10.22323/1.201.0002), [here](http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1456920/FULLTEXT01.pdf), [here](https://conference.ippp.dur.ac.uk/event/748/contributions/4317/attachments/3596/4014/Matthew_Renwick_YTF11_Talk.pdf) or [here](http://www2.yukawa.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Eschool2016/Kyoto_School2016_LectureNotes.pdf)), is:
$$
V
=
\sum_{\psi\in\{\text{fermions}\}}
\left(
(Q\psi)^{\dagger}\psi
+
\psi^{\dagger}(Q\psi^{\dagger})^{\dagger}
\right)
$$

This is where I have a little bit of a problem. All of the sources which I linked state that with this choice of $V$, the integral localizes to field configurations for which
$$
Q\psi=Q\psi^{\dagger}=\psi=\psi^{\dagger}=0
$$
although I don't understand quite why this is.

Clearly $QV$ includes the terms:
$$
\sum_{\psi\in\{\text{fermions}\}}\left(|Q\psi|^{2}+|Q\psi^{\dagger}|^{2}\right)
$$
and the sources seem to say that this is the "bosonic piece", and thus $Q\psi=Q\psi^{\dagger}=0$, but since $V$ is entirely fermionic, isn't $QV$ entirely bosonic? And furthermore, I see no reason that this implies that the fermions themselves vanish!

Obviously the two arguments have to lead to the same result, and I would really appreciate it if anybody could help me see how this happens.

Comment: Which pages in the 5 links?

Comment: Pages 102, 17, 19, 9 and 10 respectively. Sorry, I should have included this information in the original post.